# Using tr/// operator to count letters in a string

Tags: string, perl, count

I would like count number of A's, C's and G's in a sequence or string. I have written the following code.

But when I print the values, only A's get printed. C's and G's are displayed as zero.
In the code below I'm evaluating A's first, but if I switch the order by evaluating C's first, I get the values of C, but now A's and G's are printed out as zero.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(IN, "200BP_junctions_fasta.faa") or die "Cannot open the file: $!\n";
while(<IN>) 
    next if $_ =~ /\>/;
    my $a = ($_ = tr/A//);
    my $c = ($_ = tr/C//);
    my $g = ($_ = tr/G//);
    print "A:$a, C:$c, G:$g\n";
}
```

The file looks like the following:

> ```
> > A_Seq  
> ATGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGTC  
> > B_Seq  
> ATGCGATCGATCGATCGATAG
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `$_ = tr/` to `$_ =~ tr/`. Also, you're missing an open brace for your `while`.

Comment: Thank you. That was a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Because `'5'` doesn't have any `'C'`s or `'G'`s in it. You're *assigning* the value of the translation of `$_` to `$_`. If you *bind* (`$_ =~ tr//`) the operation to `$_`, you'll get the result you want.

But you really don't need to *bind* to the context variable. Binding is so that you can apply a regex or translate operation to another variable. You'd be better off writing:

```
my $a = tr/A//;
my $c = tr/C//;
my $g = tr/G//;
```

But you can do it like this, too:

```
$_{$_}++ foreach m/[ACG]/g;
say "A:$_{A}, C:$_{C}, G:$_{G}";
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer that you needed the binding operator, `=~` instead of the assignment operat0r, `=`, or that you don't need to bind the default variable.

Lately, I've been using `printf` for these sorts of things:

```
while( <DATA> ) {
    next if /\>/;
    printf "A:%s C:%s G:%s\n", tr/A//, tr/C//, tr/G//;
    }
```

I've often wished that `tr///` could interpolate so I could write this, which doesn't work:

```
while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next if $line =~ /\>/;
    print "Line is $_\n";
    printf "A:%s C:%s G:%s\n", map { $line =~ tr/$_// } qw(A C G);
    }
```

Notice that I'd have the extra annoyance of a colliding `$_` if I had used the default variable in the `while`. I know I could do an `eval`, but that's not only more of a hassle, but l4m3:

```
while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next if $line =~ /\>/;
    print "Line is $_\n";
    printf "A:%s C:%s G:%s\n", map { eval "\$line =~ tr/$_//" } qw(A C G);
    }
```

I shouldn't have to know the implementation details, though, so I could move that to a subroutine until I can figure out how to get rid of the `eval`, although extra subroutine calls may slow down big data munging:

```
while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next if $line =~ /\>/;
    print "Line is $line\n";
    printf "A:%s C:%s G:%s\n", map { count_bases( $line, $_ ) } qw(A C G);
    }

sub count_bases { eval "\$_[0] =~ tr/$_[1]//" }
```

There's probably some clever way to XOR strings if you don't like `tr///`, but I've never pursued it long enough to figure it out (not that it would be better than what you are already doing).

Answer (score 0):

```
open(IN, "input") or die "Cannot open the file: $!\n";
while(<IN>) {
  next if $_ =~ /\>/;
  my $a = @{[m/(A)/g]};
  my $c = @{[m/(C)/g]};
  my $g = @{[m/(D)/g]};
  print "A:$a, C:$c, G:$g\n";
}
```