# how to count the number of specific characters through each line from file?

Tags: perl, fasta

I'm trying to count the number of 'N's in a FASTA file which is:

```
>Header
AGGTTGGNNNTNNGNNTNGN
>Header2
AGNNNNNNNGNNGNNGNNGN
```

so in the end I want to get the count of number of 'N's and each header is a read so I want to make a histogram so I would at the end output something like this:

```
# of N's   # of Reads

0            300
1            240
```

etc...

so there are 300 sequences or reads that have 0 number of 'N's

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = shift;
my $output_file = shift;

my $line;
my $sequence;
my $length;
my $char_N_count = 0;
my @array;
my $count = 0;

if (!defined ($output_file)) {
    die "USAGE: Input FASTA file\n";
}
open (IFH, "$file") or die "Cannot open input file$!\n";
open (OFH, ">$output_file") or die "Cannot open output file $!\n";

while($line = <IFH>) {
chomp $line;
next if $line =~ /^>/;
$sequence = $line;
@array = split ('', $sequence);
foreach my $element (@array) {
if ($element eq 'N') {
$char_N_count++;
 }
 }
  print "$char_N_count\n";
 }
```

Comment: There are some stylistic issues, but apart from not setting `$char_N_count` to zero before counting the N's in each line, what is your problem?  Oh; you need an array to accumulate the count of the number of rows that contained `$char_N_count` N's...and you'll need to print that array at the end.  You'll probably need to keep track of the maximum number of N's you read in any line, too.

Comment: You can count the Ns like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538542/counting-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-inside-another-perl

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709133/using-tr-operator-to-count-letters-in-a-string

Comment: Your example output should be reflective of your example input so that a contributor can easily understand where you are and where you want to be.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I changed a few things like using scalar file handles. There are many ways to do this in Perl, so some people will have other ideas. In this case I used an array which may have gaps in it - another option is to store results in a hash and key by the count.

Edit: Just realised I'm not using $output_file, because I have no idea what you want to do with it :) Just change the 'print' at the end to 'print $out_fh' if your intent is to write to it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = shift;
my $output_file = shift;

if (!defined ($output_file)) {
    die "USAGE: $0 <input_file> <output_file>\n";
}
open (my $in_fh, '<', $file) or die "Cannot open input file '$file': $!\n";
open (my $out_fh, '>', $output_file) or die "Cannot open output file '$output_file': $!\n";

my @results = ();
while (my $line = <$in_fh>) {
    next if $line =~ /^>/;
    my $num_n = ($line =~ tr/N//);
    $results[$num_n]++;
}

print "# of N's\t# of Reads\n";

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@results) ; $i++) {
    unless (defined($results[$i])) {
        $results[$i] = 0;
        # another option is to 'next' if you don't want to show the zero totals
    }
    print "$i\t\t$results[$i]\n";
}
close($in_fh);
close($out_fh);
exit;
```