# How to count the number of zeros in a string?

Tags: perl

How to count the number of zeros in a string of this type:

```
my $string =  '11100000000010000011000';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to count the number of specific characters through each line from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325834/how-to-count-the-number-of-specific-characters-through-each-line-from-file)

Comment: I will shamelessly plug my own answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538604/725418 which has 66 upvotes at this point. :)

Comment: You can do it in following way `my $count = $str =~ s/0/0/g;`

Answer (score 7):

The traditional and fast way is to use `tr`:

```
my $count = $string =~ tr/0//;
```

Comment: I always thought the "traditional" way to count matches was to use the empty parenthesis trick: `$count = () $string =~ /0/g`.

Comment: @TLP: That's for longer strings where you can't use `tr`. Also, you need `=()=`.

Comment: Anything but the goatse operator!

Answer (score 4):

Edit: **TLDR**: The following are two most common and efficient solutions (mentioned also by other answers). For appreciation of how they work read the rest of the answer.

```perl
my $count = $string =~ tr/0//;     # solution 1
my $count = () = $string =~ /0/g;  # solution 2
```

**The long story**

So my first naive solution was this:

```perl
my $string =  '11100000000010000011000';
my @ar = split //,$string;
@b = grep { $_ == 0 } @ar;
print scalar @b,"\n";
```

While it works, it is not really a "perl-style" solution. So I looked around and found this article: https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/12/count-the-number-of-things-in-a-string/
which shows how to count the number of zeroes and ones at the same time.

Based on that I created the following:

```perl
my $string =  '11100000000010000011000';
my $count = () = $string =~ /0/g;
print "count: ",$count,"\n";
```

The most intriguing are probably the empty parentheses. They are explained in this interesting article about perl idioms:
https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=527973

Perl expression results may depend on their "context", so by using something as a scalar or as an array I tell perl what I expect to get. `()` "forces array context". Without it I would expect a scalar, which would get me `true`/`false` result of that match.

Once we have an array we `force scalar context` by assigning the array to a scalar variable and it then returns its length.

Edit: Other solutions suggested using `tr///` in the same fashion. It seems that it is maybe even more popular and it may be faster in some situations (it has to modify the string though). But the principle of the "list context" stays the same. https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators search for "list context" on that page if you want to learn more about it. It applies to most operators. But their behavior may differ.

Comment: You should probably put the good solution at the top, and the "naive" version below (or exclude it, as it is only interesting anecdotally).

Comment: @TLP I understand your point, can edit it a bit, but I disagree a bit, because most languages support basic procedural approach, but their strength is in the idioms. Though the idioms may require understanding some advanced concepts. Also, understanding how to design efficient code from basic ideas is as important as knowing the best solution. Many people can copy paste from SO to their programs, but they are not able to distil a new great solution from smaller pieces. And perl deserves more than just "copy&past this and do not ask". Just my opinion. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever it comes to counting items in Perl, I have learned, seen and used Hashes, something like this would help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# your string
my $string = '11100000000010000011000';

# has to store the item counts
my %count;

# split: read the string character by character
for my $z (split //, $string) {
    # add to the count
    $count{$z}++;
}

# read the keys of hash count
#  and sort the output
for my $k (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %count) {
    # display the counts
    print "$k has $count{$k} occurrences\n";
}
```

Results:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ perl zero.pl 
0 has 17 occurrences
1 has 6 occurrences
```